# Invalid binary operands, missing theory

Tags: function, pointers, int, syntax-error, program-entry-point

I am getting an error " invalid operands to binary * (have ‘double’ and ‘double *’)"
I must use the function as its written with pointers though the variables for x,y are normal double, so i sent in their address to make the function work . I don't get why for slope there is no error but only for *y_intercept .

```
void determine_line(double *, double *, double *, double *, double *, double *);

int main()
{
    double x1 = 0.0, x2 = 0.0, y1 = 0.0, y2 = 0.0, m = 0.0, b = 0.0;

    x1 = readValue("x1");
    y1 = readValue("y1");
    x2 = readValue("x2");
    y2 = readValue("y2");

    double *y_intercept = &b;
    double *slope = &m;

    determine_line(&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,slope,y_intercept);
    printf("\nThe points (%.2lf, %.2lf) and (%.2lf, %.2lf) are on the"
        " line: y = %.2lfx + %.2lf\n",x1,y1,x2,y2,*slope,*y_intercept);
}
void determine_line(double *x1, double *y1, double *x2, double *y2
, double *slope, double *y_intercept)
{
    *slope = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
    *y_intercept = y2 - (*slope) * x2 ; // error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the arguments to `determine_line` are pointers. You need to dereference the pointers to get the numbers that you can perform arithmetic on.

You don't get an error for the `*slope` assignment because pointer subtraction is allowed, although in this case the results are undefined because the pointers don't point to the same objects. But that line also needs dereferencing as well to produce the correct result.

```
void determine_line(double *x1, double *y1, double *x2, double *y2
, double *slope, double *y_intercept)
{
    *slope = (*y1-*y2)/(*x1-*x2);
    *y_intercept = *y2 - (*slope) * *x2 ;
}
```

It's not clear why the first 4 arguments are pointers in the first place, though. The only arguments that need to be pointers are `slope` and `intercept`, since they're used to send the results back.

Comment: Thank you , i tried it but i didnt switch it in the slope as well ^^ the question had a must for adding the coordinates as if they are pointers inside the function , though to me its useless ...